# Campos perdendo a propriedade DataSource

Tags: delphi

Estou com um projeto pequeno de alguns cadastros aqui, utilizando o Delphi XE8. às vezes, quando altero alguma coisa no projeto, todos os campos (edit´s e dbGrids) perdem a propriedade "DataSource" e tenho que ficar linkando novamente antes de compilar.

Pesquisei pela internet afora e tem muita gente que vem sofrendo com isso desde pelo menos a versão 5 do Delphi (não XE5, é a 5 mesmo).

Alguém aqui já teve esse problema? É a primeira vez que me ocorre.

Comment: Trabalho com Delphi desde o 5, sempre acompanhei a evolução da IDE, nunca passei por esta dificuldade, faça um teste, efetue e copia do DataSource, DataSet e um DBGRID ou DBEDIT (linkados) para outro formulário para ver se acontece a mesma coisa!

Comment: Pode ser que seja algum mecanismo de segurança. Digamos que ele desvincula para forçar o desenvolvedor a verificar essa determinada configuração. Como já acontece hoje quando você altera um `CommandText`, e o tipo dele muda para `ftUnknow`.
Vou dar uma pesquisada para ver se encontro alguma coisa.

Answer (score 2):

Os DataSource estão centralizados nos Formularios ou em um DataModule?

Por via de regra, toda vez que você abrir o seu projeto, abra primeiro o Form ou o DataModule onde estão os componentes de acesso(Table, Query, ClientDataSet, etc), pois se não seguir essa regra perde-se o vinculo mesmo.

[sds]

Eduardo Belo - E-mail: [redact]

Comment: Eles estão no DataModule. Sempre deixo os componentes de conexão e acesso a dados lá. Eu coloquei o DM para abrir primeiro, antes do form principal. Mas obrigado pelas dicas, vou observá-las.